# Как добавить .exe файл к python файлу pyinstaller? python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

**В общем есть 2 файла:**

- main.py
- program.exe

`main.py` запускает `program.exe` после определенного кода с помощью `os.startfile('program.exe')`

При обычных условиях всё работает корректно, но когда я использую **pyinstaller** с параметром `--add-data "program.exe;"` и запускаю полученный exe файл, он выдает ошибку, что файл не найден.

**Как это исправить? Мне надо чтобы exe файл был 1.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете относительный путь для запуска program.exe, то программа будет искать его в текущей рабочей директории, которая может быть разной при запуске исходного кода и запуске скомпилированного exe файла.

Чтобы решить эту проблему, можно использовать абсолютный путь к файлу program.exe. Для этого можно использовать функцию os.path.abspath() для получения абсолютного пути к файлу:

import os

```
# получение пути к папке с исполняемым файлом
exe_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# получение абсолютного пути к файлу program.exe
program_path = os.path.join(exe_dir, "program.exe")

# запуск program.exe
os.startfile(program_path)
```